# Who's synonymous with lack of choice?

Tags: synonyms, metaphors, analogy

I'm trying to find a well-known person who was/is famous for not allowing any choices. Eg, Henry Ford going "you can have any color as long as it's  black."

Ideas welcome!

Comment: Despite my answer below, I don't think you're going to find an example more famous than Henry Ford's.

Comment: @PaulDrye - However, Ford is remembered for many things, while Hobson is only remembered for his "choice".

Comment: Interestingly, as long as there's only one answer to this question, your choice of answers to accept is a [Hobson's choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobson%27s_choice).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about identifying a historical figure, as opposed to the English language itself.

Comment: It's a stretch, but [Procrustes](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/procrustes) might fit the bed.

Comment: @JEL - Ooooowww!!  That one was almost painful.

Answer (score 12):

Lack of a real option is called "Hobson's choice", and is supposedly [named after a real person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Hobson), ***Thomas Hobson***.

> The term "Hobson's choice" originated in the mid-seventeenth century, after Hobson's death. The poet John Milton made Hobson, and the phrase, well known, by satirising him several times in mock epitaphs

Comment: "Hobson's choice" isn't no choice at all, but rather a choice between "take it or leave it". To take the apocryphal Henry Ford example, your choices are to have a black Model-T, or to not have a (black) Model-T. Not sure if this is what the OQ was asking for or not. Up to them I guess.